# Unable to Boot OSX After Windows 10 Upgrade

Tags: macos, windows-10, boot-camp, reboot

I was running Windows 7 Home on an updated 27" iMac via bootcamp. Someone else installed it for me, so other than knowing how to reboot in either and using OSX or Windows, I don't anything about Bootcamp itself.

Everything was updated, backed up and working great. Then I decided to let Windows upgrade itself to Windows 10 Home for free. Everything went smooth. Except now I want to reboot in OSX and after searching for BootCampManager.exe. it does nothing.

Right-Clicking on the icon now in taskbar does not offer to reboot in OSX. How can I boot into OS X?

Comment: Did you check in task manager if bootcamp manager is enabled and running?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to boot into OS X is to do a full shutdown. After you have hit the power button to turn the computer on, hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key. Once you do this, you will be able to select your operating system there. I find this to be the best option.

It will look like so:

[image]

You can also reinstall the [Boot Camp Support software](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1837?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) on Windows, to regain that shortcut in the taskbar.

Remember that Boot Camp has no actual control over Windows - Boot Camp itself is just an assistant to make the process of installing and running Windows on an Apple computer easier.